# Find next free integer using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one table in which i store document properties and for each new document with a specific properties i need to increment integer which identifies that document. 
This is my select query:

```
SELECT tip, broj, god, sifra, objekt FROM docs.dok_sta_d;
```

In this table I need to increment 'sifra' column.

This should be my Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `docs`.`dok_sta_d` (`tip`, `broj`, `god`, `sifra`, `objekt`) VALUES ('12', '777', '2', 'integer', '9');
```

In column 'sifra' i should add a next integer based on other values (`tip`, `broj`, `god`,`objekt`) so that 'sifra' field starts from 1 for each new combination of other values and it increments by 1 for each combination of values that is already in table.

Comment: In general, this kind of strategy is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

As a pseudocode, it should be in below. Please make your corrections.

```
INSERT INTO `docs`.`dok_sta_d` 
select name,
      @rownum := @rownum + 1 as row_number
from `docs`.`dok_sta_d`
```

Comment: What's @rownum?

Comment: To make this fly, you're gonna at least need to cater for `@rownum` being initially `null` by using `coalesce()`: `@rownum := coalesce(@rownum, 0) + 1`